# What do I need to add to use "using System.Timers;"?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I work in xamarin forms and I need to use this assembly (using System.Timers;) but when I write it now it does not find Timers. Do I need to add a package?

I want to use it like this:

```
       var timer = new Timer (1000);
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        timer.Start ();

public static void OnTimerElapsed(object o, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
 //code
 }
```

Comment: can you show the code in reference to what you are talking about so that others can see what it is you are doing..? also do a google search on `C# Xamarin Ststem.Timer`

Comment: yeah give me 1minute.

Comment: `System.Timers` is on `System.dll`. But if you are using on a PCL it might be limited and you have to use something else. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: updated with code now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to use the Timer class in the PCL project? If so you will have to use [Device.StartTimer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/device/#Device.StartTimer)

```
Device.StartTimer (new TimeSpan (0, 0, 60), () => {
    // do something every 60 seconds
    return true; // runs again, or false to stop
});
```

Comment: @medvedo: Are you trying to use it in Portable Class Library project?

Comment: I am doing a regular xamarin forms project with iOS and android

Comment: I have a sampleproject that is in xamarin forms aswell that uses this code and it finds using system.timers for that project. but when I try to make a new project i cannot find system.timers

Comment: @medvedo: Xamarin.Forms solution consists of multiple projects. In which project are you trying to use the timer?

Comment: how can I adjust this code and run my OnTimerElapsed function with your code above?

Comment: @medvedo: Replace  // do something every 60 seconds

Comment: oh ok, so i can just put the code right in there. and it will loop every 60 seconds in this case then?

Comment: @medvedo: Yes. Did you check the link in the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108864/discussion-between-giorgi-and-medvedo).

Answer (score 0):

System.Timers is coming from the System.dll assembly.
Here is the inforamation from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the PCL profile, the Timer class won't be available. I use this snippet of code instead:

```
    delegate void TimerCallback(object state);

    sealed class Timer : CancellationTokenSource, IDisposable
    {
        internal Timer(TimerCallback callback, object state, int dueTime, int period)
        {
            if (dueTime <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dueTime", "Must be positive integer");

            if (period <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("period", "Must be positive integer");

            Task.Delay(dueTime, Token).ContinueWith(async (t, s) =>
                {
                    var tuple = (Tuple<TimerCallback, object>)s;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (IsCancellationRequested)
                            break;
                        Task.Run(() => tuple.Item1(tuple.Item2));
                        await Task.Delay(period);
                    }

                }, Tuple.Create(callback, state), CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
        }

        public new void Dispose()
        {
            Cancel();
        }
    }
```

Comment: i used a xamarin forms example project before that uses system.timers but when i try to remake a project and add that i cannot find it which is weird because that sample project is a xamarinforms project